# google oauth in golang:oauth2: cannot fetch token: 401 Unauthorized Response: { "error": "invalid_client", "error_description": "Unauthorized" }

Tags: go, oauth, google-oauth, exchange-server, unauthorized

I tried to use Oauth2.0 by google
That error occurred the moment I selected the account to log in.

```golang
func googleAuthCallbackHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    oauthstate, err := r.Cookie("oauthstate")
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("oauthstate is not Founded%s", err.Error())
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
    }
    if r.FormValue("state") != oauthstate.Value {
        log.Printf("invalid google oauth state cookie: %s state:%s\n", oauthstate.Value, r.FormValue("state"))
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
    }

    data, err := getGoogleUserInfo(r.FormValue("code"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to load code value %s", err.Error())
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
    }
    fmt.Fprint(w, string(data))
}

func getGoogleUserInfo(code string) ([]byte, error) {
    token, err := googleOauthConfig.Exchange(context.Background(), code)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Failed to Exchange %s\n", err.Error())
    }
    res, err := http.Get(oauthGoogleUrlAPI + token.AccessToken)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Failed to Get User Info %s\n", err.Error())
    }

    return ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
}
```

err code:

```
021/06/04 12:19:32 4/0AY0e-g79Vb8Up5fvjuel39ssTaf0Hf__Amfm8TO3qbaIKHc2kSk63jB9Mso8JS96rYTS8Q
2021/06/04 12:19:32 Failed to load code value Failed to Exchange oauth2: cannot fetch token: 401 Unauthorized
Response: {
  "error": "invalid_client",
  "error_description": "Unauthorized"
}
```

I think the exchange function is causing a problem, but I don't know what it is.
plz help me

thank you

Comment: Does your client correctly post the value `code`? Try inserting `fmt.Printf("code: %s\n", code)` at the first line in `getGoogleUserInfo` and check the value is correct.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the sample for the people api, [sample](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/go) its much more reliable then using the userinfo endpoint